# windows 10 cant RDC to windows 7

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, vpn, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 7, 64 bit PC at work... a Windows 7, 64 bit PC at home... and a Windows 10, 64 bit PC at home.

I've installed Cisco VPN client onto both home PC's.

I'm able to connect using the VPN client, and the client shows "Connected", on both home PC's.

- When I try to Remote Desktop from Windows 10, to my work PC by computer name, I get the "Connecting to: [computer name]"..."Initializing Remote Connection" dialog... but after about 10 seconds it errors and I get the "Remote desktop can't connect"..."make sure remote computer is turned on" garbage.
- The Remote Desktop connection works just fine from home Win 7 PC to Work Win 7 PC.
- I've tried manually turning on the Remote Desktop Service, to no avail.

Comment: Are you able to ping your work PC from the Win10 PC?

Comment: good point, no I am not.  so this means that i'm not actually connected, even if the VPN client says so...?

Comment: Did you try disabling the firewall on the Win10 machine (briefly, then reenable) to see if it solves the problem?

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem, did anyone find a solution?

Comment: @RickyStam Sort of -- the issue ended up being the VPN client, not the RDC application.  It seems the old Cisco VPN client doesn't support windows 10 without a lot of hacking around.  Cisco's newer VPN client, AnyConnect, works great from windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being the VPN client, not the RDC application. It seems the old Cisco VPN client doesn't support windows 10 without a lot of hacking around. Cisco's newer VPN client, AnyConnect, works great from windows 10